# How to make integration test for DB at google App. engine?

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine

I'am wondering, how to write integration tests, that involves DB interaction, for Google app engine?

It's seems - no problem to run this test at Google, on "live" db, using GAEUnit [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107675/how-can-i-unit-test-responses-from-the-webapp-wsgi-application-in-google-app-engi)
But, this seems bad practice to me, because it's live environment.

Google has provided examples of such tests, for java, but not for python [link](http://graphics.sci.ubu.ac.th/api/google-appengine/appengine/docs/java/howto/unittesting.html).
Do anybody know how to setup database locally, during test setup on python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also want to take a look at [Fixture](http://farmdev.com/projects/fixture/using-fixture-with-appengine.html). It lets you easily create datasets that are loaded in a datastore stub at the beginning of every test. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753897/what-approaches-have-you-used-for-lightweight-python-unit-tests-on-app-engine/3515022#3515022) has a specific example.

Answer (score 0):

Use [NoseGAE](http://farmdev.com/projects/nosegae/). It sets up the development environment so you can test datastore and other APIs. Then, and this one is not required, [gaetestbed](http://github.com/jgeewax/gaetestbed/) provides some helpers to cleanup datastore or memcache etc between tests.